# How does unique_ptr behave after the object it points to has a memory reallocation?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management, smart-pointers

Suppose I have the following code:

```cpp
class container {
public:
    container() {
        mContainer = std::make_unique<std::map<std::string, std::string>>();
    }
    void add(const string& k, const string& v) {
        (*mContainer)[k] = v;
    }
...
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::map<std::string, std::string>> mContainer;
}
```

My question is:
Will this `mContainer` still be valid after the map it points to has a memory reallocation?

Comment: Maps don't do reallocation (in the way that `std::vector` does). And why should the `std::unique_ptr` care at all how the `std::map` manages its internal memory?

Comment: Pointer (or iterator) invalidations happen because the pointer is pointing at the *internals* of an object. A pointer to the object itself is never invalid as long as the object exists. The object's address never changes.

Comment: but also, why have a unique_ptr to a map, why not have the map directly in the class. its just a level of indirection you dont need

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr` is designed to be the **owner** of the managed object, hence why it's called "unique". It doesn't matter what the managed object does with its own internals. As long as *you* don't modify the pointer to it, it will remain valid.